# Regular expression for indian mobile number in Angular

Tags: angular, regex, mobile

1. It should accept mobile number starting with 0 or 6 to 9.
2. If the number starts with 6 to 9 then the length of the number will be 10 digit.
3. And if the number starts with 0 then the length of the number will be 11 digit.

Comment: kindly share what you tried?

Comment: /^[6-9]\d{9}$/  @JustIn

Comment: I posted an answer, please test on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Correct answer is
/^(?:[0])?[6-9][0-9]{9}$/

if first digit between 6 to 9 then length 10 digit.
and if first digit is 0 then second digit between 6 to 9 and length 11 digit.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```regex
^(?:[6-9]|0\d)\d{9}$
```

This pattern matches:

```regex
^      from the start of the number
(?:
[6-9]  starts with 6, 7, 8, or 9            (one digit, total 10 digits)
|      OR
0\d    starts with 0 followed by any digit  (two digits, total 11 digits)
)
\d{9}  followed by 9 more digits
$      end of the number
```

Comment: if starts with 0 then it should be followed by numbers between 6 to 9.  @Tim

Answer (score 1):

- ? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many
  times as possible, giving back as needed
- **Match a single character present in the list below [0]:**
  0 matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)
- **Match a single character present in the list below [6-9]:**
  6-9 matches a single character in the range between 6 (index 54) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- **Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]:**
  {9} matches the previous token exactly 9 times
- **g:** modifier: global. All matches (don't return after the first match)
- **m:** modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of the string)

So, we can do it like

```
/^(?:[0])?[6-9][0-9]{9}$/gm
```